# CGImageMaskCreate in ios4.1

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimageview, uiimage, imagemagick

I am using the below masking code:-

```
- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)im withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage;

    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([im CGImage], mask);
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to support iOS 4.1? If you want to support iOS 6 you will need to drop support for iOS 4.2 and lower.

Comment: @rckoenes Thanks for the quick reply cant i make an if condition for IOS version and make it  able to support in all IOS?

Comment: If you use the iOS 6 SDK you will not be able to build for iOS 4.2 or lower. The minimal version is 4.3 and a ARMv7 processor device. If you mean an `#if` macro then no, these are compile time based, if you are talking about a regular if, then yes. But you still can't compile for iOS 4.2 if you are using the iOS 6 SDK, I dropped support for any thing blow 4.3 and ARMv6 processors.

Comment: @rckoenes But it is making the same issue in 4.3 also.I am having IOS4.3 and armv7.But still same.IS there no solution regarding this?

Comment: es gibt kein frage… or in plain english: what was your question?